# GLES2.0 - Not sure I am using glTexImage2D correctly

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

a novice in this matter, and lost almost 3 days of work with no luck trying to figure out the problem.

Scope:

Want to assign one 1 unique color to an obj

What I have done:

```
// Align color
GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "alignColor: glActiveTexture");
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "alignColor: glbindtexture");
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "alignColor: glTexParameteri1");
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "alignColor: glTexParameteri2");


ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
IntBuffer ib = bb.asIntBuffer();
ib.put(0x0e5865ff);
ib.position(0);
bb.position(0);

GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
ShaderUtil.checkGLError(TAG, "alignColor: texImage2D");
```

Issue:

Color assigned is not what is expected. 
In this case I am expecting:

```
R 0e --> 14
G 58 --> 88
B 65 --> 101
A ff --> alpha 255
```

A greenish color while I am having a red one

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That works but if I put eg ib.put(0xffdeff00); instead of Yellowish I have blueish

Answer (score 0):

Ended up usin Android GLUtils , which will automatically detect the format.

Got the color
Created 1px Btimap
Passed it to GLUtils

```
Bitmap textureBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
textureBitmap.setPixel(0,0,localColorInt);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textureBitmap, 0);
```